# Haskell: Couldn't match expected type

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to learn Haskell and the small bit of sample code I tried to understand is compiling, but while applying the code I was running into a  "Couldn't match expected type" error.
Can anyone give me some guidance as to what I'm doing wrong/how I should go about this?

This code was given in a lecture:

```
> mult :: Integer -> (Integer, Integer-> Integer )
> mult x = (x,(*x))
```

Executing `snd (mult 3) 5` as I was told in the lecture I get

```
15
```

However when executing `(mult 3) 5` I get the following error

```
<interactive>:133:1: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Integer -> t’
                  with actual type ‘(Integer, Integer -> Integer)’
    • The function ‘mult’ is applied to two arguments,
      but its type ‘Integer -> (Integer, Integer -> Integer)’
      has only one
      In the expression: (mult 3) 5
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = (mult 3) 5
    • Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at <interactive>:133:1)
```

Seeing the error I have tried to apply `mult` with one argument `mult 3` which resulted in the following error

```
<interactive>:135:1: error:
    • No instance for (Show (Integer -> Integer))
        arising from a use of ‘print’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Why can't I use `mult` without the `snd` function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
(Integer, Integer -> Integer)
```

This is not a function. It might *look* kind of like a function of two arguments, but it's actually parenthesized as `(Integer, (Integer -> Integer))`

so it's a tuple, where the first thing is just an ordinary number and the second is a function.

```
mult :: Integer -> (Integer, Integer -> Integer)
mult x = (x, (*x))
```

Here, we take a number `x` and return a 2-tuple. The first element of this tuple is just the number `x`, nothing more and nothing less. The second element is a function which multiplies by `x`. These are two distinct values, not tied together in any way.

```
fst (mult 3)
```

This is the first element of the tuple, which is just a number. In this case, we'll get `3`.

```
snd (mult 3)
```

This is the second element of the tuple, a function from `Integer` to `Integer`. We can't print out functions in Haskell (since they don't implement `Show`), so we have to apply it to an argument in order to get a result.

```hs
snd (mult 3) 5 -- Or, equivalently, (snd (mult 3)) 5
```

This applies the function "multiply by 3" to the number 5, so we get 5 times 3, or `15`.

```
(mult 3) 5
```

This takes a tuple `mult 3` (whose value is `(x, (* x))`), and attempts to apply it to a number. In Haskell, *only* functions can be given arguments, and a tuple is not a function, so you get an error that basically says "I expected a function here, but I got a tuple".

Answer (score 3):

> Why can't I use `mult` without the `snd` function?

Because `mult 5` returns a 2-tuple, it returns `(5, (* 5))`, so the first item is an `Integer` whereas the second is a function with type `Integer -> Integer`.

You cannot use this 2-tuple as a function when you apply `3` to it. What would the result of `(5, (* 5)) 3` be? By using `snd (5, (* 5))` it returns `(* 5)`, and then you can use that for `(* 5) 3`, which is `15`.

Furthermore you cannot use `show f` with `f` a function, since for a generic function, that cannot produce output. Using printing the result of `mult 3` is thus not possible, you can print `fst (mult 3)` for example, which is `3`.